# can we resize button on adaptive card being rendered on MS Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I want to resize and change the color of the action buttons in adaptive cards being rendered on MS Teams.How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to resize the action button but there is a new feature introduced in Adaptive card which allows you to give a style to your button. Please try this out in [Adaptive cards designer](https://adaptivecards.io/designer/).